# Error page fails with XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: http://localhost:8080/3c/login/Login.xhtml Line Number 1, Column 1

Tags: jsf, exception, facelets, viewexpiredexception

I would like to handle `ViewExpiredException` on non-ajax requests (PrimeFaces with `ajax="false"`). I've configured an error page on that exception in `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpages/expired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

When the view expired exception occurs, the following is logged:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with
>   path [/3c] threw exception [viewId:/login/Login.xhtml - View
>   /login/Login.xhtml could not be restored.] with root cause
>   javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException:
>   viewId:/login/Login.xhtml - View /login/Login.xhtml could not be
>   restored.     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:205)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:116)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

However, instead of the error page content, the browser shows a yellow page with message:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found
>   Location: http://example.com:8080/3c/login/Login.xhtml Line Number 1, Column 1:

Why is the content of `/errorpages/expired.xhtml` not shown?

Comment: No i am not able to see any line in console and its not ajax request I just press the button which is nonajax request because i made `ajax="false"`

Comment: Ok my mistake let me try with ajax request as well ...can not i made changes so that omnifaes error handling will work with ajax and nonajax request

Comment: ANy idea how to test if the Normal exception handling working or not ?

Comment: Hmm but it is also true "smart and eager" these word perfectly fit on you as well :)

Comment: Oh that ,i do not know and Stack Exchange will not answer me why @BalusC not eager now :( A expert in lots of Java technology .